# Unable to use wget for downloading git hub search results

Tags: linux, git, github, wget

I am trying to use wget to download github code search results into a logfile.

I've been using the following command :

```
    wget -o logfile -r -l 2 https://github.com/search?l=Dockerfile&q=openjdk&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93
```

I do however, get a robots.txt file that says the following :

# If you would like to crawl GitHub contact us at support@github.com.

# We also provide an extensive API: https://developer.github.com/

Do I need some sort of permission from github for this?
Can someone help?

Answer (score -1):

I think the message is pretty clear: you're trying to crawl GitHub site and they don't like that.

They advise you to use the [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/).

The [v3 API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) is still REST, so you could do something like:

```
wget --output-document search-results.json --user <YOUR_GITHUB_ID> \
"https://api.github.com/search/code?q=openjdk+language:Dockerfile"
```